# Help solving this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$dy/dt= (1-y)^3$

can someone show me step by step how to solve this? The methods I know so far are separation of variables, variation of parameters, and integration factors.

Can I use separation of variables here?

Comment: @Amzoti how do I integrate 1/(1-y)^3 dy?

Comment: is it (1-y)^-2/-2?

Answer (score 3):

The "trick" in separating variables is bringing all $y$s and $dy$s to one side and all $t$s with $dt$s to the other side and then integrating:
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=(1-y)^3$$
$$\frac{1}{(1-y)^3}dy=dt$$
$$\int \frac{1}{(1-y)^3}dy=\int dt$$
 ($C$ is an arbitrary constant)
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(1-y)^2}=t+C$$
So:
$$1-y=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2t+2C}}$$
hence:
$$y(t)=1\mp \frac{1}{\sqrt{2t+2C}}$$

Comment: how did you go from the third to last step to the second to last step? I tried multiplying each side by 2 but then I would have 2t +2c on the right

Comment: Is the integral the problem? If you like you can define $u:=1-y$ then $du=-dy$ and we get $$\int \frac{1}{(1-y)^3}dy=\int \frac{-1}{u^3}du=\frac{-1}{2}\frac{-1}{u^3}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(1-y)^3}$$

Comment: I understand how you got that I'm just confused with the algebra for solving for y for some reason..

Comment: Oh, actually you're right, I made a mistake there. I'll edit it.

Comment: taking the square root of 1/(1-y)^2 brings the 1-y to the numerator?

Comment: @Lil No, I am also taking the reciprocal of both sides.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the change of variable $u = 1- y.$ it will give you $$-\frac{du}{dt} = u^3$$ which can be separated as $$-\frac{du}{u^3} = dt$$ and integrated as $$\frac 1{2u^2} = t+ C$$

putting it back in the original variable gives you $$\frac{1}{(y-1)^2} = 2(t+C).$$

the last equation is equivalent to $$y-1 = \pm \frac 1{\sqrt{(2t + 2C)}}$$ that is $$y = 1 \pm \frac 1{\sqrt{(2t + 2C)}} $$ the initial condition on $y$ will help pick the right sign.

Comment: alright I understand up to this point. How can I solve for y at this point though?

Comment: @Lil, the sign it depends on the initial condition but $y= 1 \pm 1/\sqrt{2t+2C}$

Comment: Right now I have (2t+2c)^1/2=1/1-y how do I get to your final answer from here?

Comment: @Lil, you need a $\pm$ sign there. you can flip your fractions  to read $\pm 1/\sqrt{2t+2C} = 1 - y$

Comment: ok. Does taking the square root of 1/(1-y)^2 move the 1-y to the numerator?

Comment: sorry can you just show these last steps worked out? I don't seem to understand how the fraction disappears..

Comment: two comments ago you had $\pm \sqrt{2t+2C} = \frac 1{1-y}.$ you can write that as $1-y = \pm 1/\sqrt{2t+2C}$

Comment: and then subtract one from both sides and divide by -1 to solve for y as the final answer?